# Sencha Touch application with grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

I have been using ExtJS for a while now, and used it build an application that gets data in JSON format and presents it to the user in a grid. I want to replicate this application on mobile devices. I've looked at the examples for Sencha Touch, but I was not able to find an example of a grid.

I want build a grid with a grouped header - something like [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/group-header-grid.html), using Sencha Touch.

I also looked at the [documentation](http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/docs/#!/guide) of Sencha Touch components but could not find anything.

Please let me know what options I have to build a grid using Sencha Touch. Is it possible to create a grid with multiple headers using Sencha Touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a commercial license for Sencha Touch (and a small budget), you can check out the [UberGrid](http://www.bryntum.com/products/ubergrid/) component developed by Bryntum. Unfortunately, though, the license isn't compatible with Sencha Touch GPL - details can be found at the [Bryntum FAQ](http://www.bryntum.com/store/ubergrid/#faq), including information about discounts for charitable/educational applications.

Short of that, you'll have to either find a community extension or build your own, as Sencha Touch doesn't include any built-in grid component.

Answer (score -1):

I realise that this question is old. But Sencha since then seem to have released a grid (albeit in paid versions).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Removed the link if that makes any difference.